# Exception Handling Help (Java)

Tags: java, exception

Trying to grasp exception handling, but I'm not sure I understand just yet. What SHOULD be happening is if the user inputs something other than an integer, the mismatchexception should execute and print that friendly message. Also, on the topic of exception handling, if my code has any useless exceptions in it, let me know (and why if you  don't mind). Full code linked below. Thanks!

```
public static void addRecords() {
    System.out.print("Hello, welcome to my magical program!\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter integer no. %d: ", i + 1);
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        {
            try {
                output.format("Inputted integer: %s%n", String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
            } catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedexception) {
                System.err.println("Error writing to the file. Terminating.");
                break;
            } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
                System.err.println("Please restart the program and enter integers ONLY.");
                break;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException elementException) {
                System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full code here:
http://pastebin.com/eSGau5ax

Comment: Why ask if you can just try and see for yourself? If the exception is not handled, you'll see exactly what exception was thrown and not caught by catch.

Comment: Why ask if you can just try .

Comment: I tried, but got this:

Hello, welcome to my magical program!
Please enter integer no. 1: a
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at average.Average.addRecords(Average.java:52)
 at average.Average.main(Average.java:25)

I don't find that it helped me too much.

Comment: You get an exception on input.nextInt(); If you wanna catch that exception you should have input.nextInt(); inside the try.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,**

`java.util.InputMismatchException` happens for your data file `numbers.txt` not containing integer type data. Please input relative data. It will solve this inputmismatchexception.
For your better understanding, follow the tutorial:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-util-inputmismatchexception-how-to-solve-inputmismatchexception/

**Next,**

Use this code. It may help you.

Actually what you have posted in http://pastebin.com/eSGau5ax.

There are 2 errors.

First one error occurred in

```
 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("numbers.txt"))){
```

But I changed it like that because there was some error.

```
            try{
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("numbers.txt"));
```

Another error was related to taking input section must be in try catch. But I have not run your code. All credit goes to other SO helpers.

```
numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
```

Now your code is looks like

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;

public class Average {

    private static Formatter output;

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int[] numbers = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openFile();
        addRecords();
        closeFile();
        readRecords();
    }

    public static void openFile() {
        try {
            output = new Formatter("numbers.txt");
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            System.err.println("Write permission denied. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void addRecords() {
        System.out.print("Hello, welcome to my magical program!\n");
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.printf("Please enter integer no. %d: ", i + 1);
                numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println();
                output.format("Inputted integer: %s%n", String
                        .valueOf(numbers[i]));
            }
        } catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedexception) {
            System.err.println("Error writing to the file. Terminating.");
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
            System.err
                    .println("Please restart the program and enter integers ONLY.");
            break;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException elementException) {
            System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
            input.nextLine();
        }

    }

    public static void closeFile() {
        {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
        }
    }

    public static void readRecords() {

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("numbers.txt"));
            String line;
            int[] number = new int[10];
            int i = -1;
            int sum = 0;
            double average = 0;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                i++;
                String[] split = line.split(":");
                line = split[1].trim();
                number[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
                System.out.printf("Integer number %d: %d%n", i, numbers[i]);
                sum += number[i];
                average = (double) sum / 10;
            }

            System.out.printf("%nWould your sum happen to be %d? %n", sum);
            System.out.printf("Which means your average is: %.2f %n", average);

        } catch (NoSuchFileException noSuchFileException) {
            System.out
                    .print("This file was not created properly and cannot be found.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.out
                    .print("I can't seem to find your file :( That's too bad...");
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {
            System.out
                    .print("Whoopsie daisy, you got yourself an IOException. Better luck next time!");
        } finally {
            System.out
                    .print("Check your numbers.txt file and see what ya got!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't even try to explain where OPs problem was ... well and it also doesn't fix that problem.

Comment: *"The error occurred in `try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("numbers.txt"))){`"* ... so the `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException` happens there? Does this makes sense?

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your complement. Mismatch is happens for input data type or pattern mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to throw the exception from the methods and catch them in the main method. The methods should not decide what to do with the exceptions, its upto the caller (main method in this case) to decide whether to print it or log it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to catch an Exception that happened outside of the `try`.
Just get the nextInt inside the `try`

```
public static void addRecords() {
    System.out.print("Hello, welcome to my magical program!\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter integer no. %d: ", i + 1);
        System.out.println();
        {
            try {
                numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
                output.format("Inputted integer: %s%n", String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
            } catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedexception) {
                System.err.println("Error writing to the file. Terminating.");
                break;
            } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
                System.err.println("Please restart the program and enter integers ONLY.");
                break;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException elementException) {
                System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```